# Is it possible to display certain number of objects from a list in a dropdown? (but keep rest available for search)

Tags: html, angular, jquery-select2, dropdown, angular-services

In my dropdown for now all of the products are displayed, and I have like 200 products there, and dropdown is pretty large, I would like to display only 5-10 product for example, so it might look like this:

[image]

So basically all of the products would be there available for search, **BUT ONLY** 5 - 10 of them would be displayed, so dropdown would look more cleaner..

This is pure html of dropdown:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <select class="form-control dash-form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
        <option selected disabled>Search...</option>
        <option>258-656 - Product 1 0,5l</option>
        <option>358-656 - Product 2 0,75l</option>
        <option>428-656 - Product 3 1kg</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And this is Angular modified:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <select class="form-control dash-form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
        <option selected disabled>Search...</option>
        <option *ngFor="let p of products;" [value]="p.id">{{product.title}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And this angular way of course display all the values that are contained in `products` array.. and that's not it:)

Any kind of help would be awesome

Thanks guys

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

In your component, import `FormControl` from `@angular/forms` and create an observable that takes a Product[].

```
public productCtrl: FormControl = new FormControl();
public products$: Observable<Product[]>;
```

now introduce a cold-observable that listens to input on the form-control, but until then, display the first 5 items.

```
this.products$ = this.productCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(
   debounceTime(500),
   startWith(null)
   map(this.filterOrFirstFiveElements) 
   // implement a function
   // that filters and returns your current product array or returns first five elements
   // when a filter is provided and you get more that five elements, you can still only return first five elements of that result
);
```

Now in your template go ahead and adjust it to use the observable and mark the control as form-control.

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <select class="form-control dash-form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
        <option selected disabled>Search...</option>
        <option *ngFor="let p of products$ | async;" [value]="p.id">{{product.title}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
<input type="text" [formControl]="productsCtrl" />
```

You need to import reactive-forms module into your module in order to be able to use `[FormControl]` directive.

**Not directly related:** As a user I would be completely confused when I see only five elements, use the filter and get a completely different result. An autocomplete is maybe a better solution. Show nothing, until user searches for a product.

Answer (score 1):

Use Pipe

```
filter.pipe.ts

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    console.log(args)
    if(!value){
      return null;
    }
    let arg=args ? args :5;
    let limitTo=value.length >5 ? value.slice(0,arg) : value ;

    return limitTo;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let d of data |filterpipe:5">
  {{d.name}}
</div>
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r3kpxc

Answer (score 0):

You could just use an index:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <select class="form-control dash-form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
        <option selected disabled>Search...</option>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let p of products; let i = index;" >
          <option *ngIf="i < 5" [value]="p.id">{{product.title}}</option>
        </ng-container>
    </select>
</div>
```